# Fetch XML feed in php

Tags: php, xml, for-loop

I am a newbie to PHP, How can I Read the following XML feed in PHP, I Tried to fetch the feed using PHP for loop, But I can't please help me, Thanks

Here is the feed url https://www.polimernews.com/apis/rss/Headlines

```
$i=0;
foreach($data1->details as $row) {
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($row_1); echo '</pre>';         
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($row).$i; echo '</pre>';
      //echo $row->row_.$i->title;
      $i++;
}
```

[image: Image Attached]

Comment: The problem is in fetching the XML or on the loop? Can you please add the code in which you fetch the XML?

Comment: @David Winder, i have to fetch all the titles of the feed in XML, How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I guess you want to print all row_* from the feed.

You can do so like in the following code example:

```
$url = 'https://www.polimernews.com/apis/rss/Headlines';
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$array = array();
foreach(new SimpleXMLElement($response) as $k => $v) {
     $array[$k] = $v;
}

foreach($array["details"] as $row) {
      echo "Here is the current row: \n";
      echo print_r($row);
}
```

Notice that every row is an xml object so I print it using print_r command